# Rectificated images doesn't complain epipolar geometry

Tags: matlab, stereoscopy, disparity-mapping

I am trying to obtain a disparity map from a homemade stereo camera setup. The baseline is 125mm and both cameras are fixed to a 3D-printed support. I've previously calibrated the cameras with 15 images of a checkboard pattern of 80mm square size  using MatLab's calibration tool.

Using the intrinsics an extrinsics given by MatLab calibration tool, I rectified the images and build the disparity map on a MatLab script. However, the disparity is not good enough for my application. Do you think the calibration is not good or could be due to other problems?

Here are the results:
[image: Epipolar constraint doesn't apply]
As you see through the lines I draw, the rectification of the images is not well done, since the epipolar constraint doesn't apply.
[image: disparity map]
As you can see I used one of the calibration images to check. However, it happens the same on other images. I'm particularly concerned about the ground, as it contains a lot of noise and invalid points, which is not good enough for my algorithms, so I need to improve it.

Comment: The rectification is terrible. If your matching functions takes as input rectified images, then it will fail for sure in this setup. Try to recalibrate your system and make sure that the epipolar constrains hold after rectification. For example the corresponding corner of a checkerboard square must be in the same epipolar line. You can also use [Matlab's vgg_gui](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/code/) to check that epipolar constrains hold prior and after rectification.

Comment: I know it is terrible, yes, I have recalibrated a couple of times, but with the same images. ¿Does the fact that the camera lenses are dirty or a moved image affect so much the calibration?

Comment: does the calibration toolbox detect the checkerboard patterns correctly? Are your intrinsic and extrinsic parameter estimation consistent when you recalibrate the system? How do you rectify the images?

Comment: Yes, when I recalibrate the results are very near. I rectify using rectifyStereoImages function from MatLab with the parameters of the calibration. And yes, the matlab calibration toolbox detect the edges quite accurately

Comment: Have you checked your reprojection error? may give you an estimate of the quality of your calibration